# After sorting table Bootgrid reset values

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I am generating checkboxes in my Bootgrid table and after click on one checkbox I am changing value in DB (0 and 1) using ajax post call.... Everything works and looks find in Bootgrid table, but if I click on table header to sort column (first or last name or something else) Bootgrid automatically reset all values from checkboxes at the previous state, so how can I force bootgrid to always take **last/as is** state as default.

I have tried with `$('#exampleTable').refresh();` but it is the same (reverting change)

Here is my code

```
$('#exampleTable').bootgrid({
  rowCount: [10],
  css: {
    ...
  },
  formatters: {
    ...,
    'emailDocument': function (column, row) {
      let isChecked = row.emailDocument ? 'checked' : '';
      let userID = row.userId;
      let elementId = 'emailDocuments';
      let userRootSettings = parseInt(row.userRootSettings);
      return getToggleButton(elementId, userID, isChecked);
    },
    ...
  }
}).on('click.rs.jquery.bootgrid', function (e, cols, row) {
  if (typeof row != 'undefined') {
    $('#emailDocuments' + row.userId).unbind().click(function () {
      let newSettingValue = row.emailDocument ? 0 : 1;
      updateUserAddressSettings('documentsPerEmail', row.userAddressId, newSettingValue);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: any updates? Running in the same problem...